# Jasig cas 4.0.0 | Google oauth exception

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, jasig

I have done everything as in the tutorials of official cas.

When redirecting from google's page to my cas application I am getting the following exception.

```
2014-08-06 11:26:01,286 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <ClientAuthenticationHandler failed authenticating org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.authentication.principal.ClientCredential@bad528>
2014-08-06 11:26:01,358 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: supplied credentials: [org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.authentication.principal.ClientCredential@bad528]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Aug 06 11:26:01 NPT 2014
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.0.2.2
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.0.2.15
=============================================================

>
2014-08-06 11:26:01,414 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: 1 errors, 0 successes
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Aug 06 11:26:01 NPT 2014
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.0.2.2
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.0.2.15
=============================================================

>
2014-08-06 11:26:01.487:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction@e5c8 in state 'clientAction' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
    at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction@e5c8 in state 'clientAction' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:222)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
```

When I open the Cas login page again and hit the "login with google" button again, It shows that the login is successful. But It always fails the first time.
Could someone help me out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different thing, I tried changing the scope of the client.

Previously I was using scope to be EMAIL and it was failing. When I used EMAIL_AND_PROFILE, it worked correctly.

```
    <bean id="google1" class="org.pac4j.oauth.client.Google2Client">
      <property name="key" value="<key>" />
      <property name="secret" value="<secret_value>" />
      <property name="scope" value="EMAIL_AND_PROFILE" />
    </bean>
```